# How to use local storage on phonegap?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, local-storage, storage

I started using phonegap for a note taking app. Now how can i use cordova local storage or something similar for saving, removing and editing notes.I'm also using angularjs and ionic framework.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use localStorage object that comes with html5, you don't need to do anything special for cordova, since you are already inside a webview with local storage support.

Here is an intro to local storage in html5 if you haven't seen already:
http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Answer (score 1):

Html can be used for local storage or java script. If you are also using native code(objectivec/android) you can use sqllite too for storage.html5 is best option.

Methods for local storage in html5

1)window.localStorage -     stores data with no expiration
2)  datecode.sessionStorage - stores data for one session (data is lost when the tab is closed)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a blog post about how to use localStorage in Cordova/Ionic Framework : http://blog.glaucocustodio.com/2015/03/30/local-storage-with-alasql-in-cordovaionic-framework/

Answer (score 0):

In my ionic projects I use [angular-localForage](https://github.com/ocombe/angular-localForage), an excellent angular module, which provides services and directives for https://github.com/mozilla/localForage. So you can use WebSQL, IndexedDB or LocalStorage with the same localStorage-like API.